# Updating like count of a Facebook page programmatically

Tags: api, facebook

I am developing a iPhone application that uses Facebook APIs. 
Which API should I use for incrementing the like count of a Facebook page?

Thanks and regards,
Deepa

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the Like count. It will update itself if users start liking the page.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I need to provide the feature that programmatically likes a Page in the Facebook. Do you have any idea about Facebook API that does this required job for me.